# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: when compile two cpp files in terminal

Tags: c++, macos

I'm new in cpp and when I compile two cpp files in terminal and shows the error as followed
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "func(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main-45889e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

here are my codes:
main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "func.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    func(1);
    return 0;
}
```

func.cpp

```
#include "func.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int func(int a){
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

func.hpp

```
int func(int a);
```

it succeed when I use Xcode to run the code while failed when using terminal to compile with the following g++ commands:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c func.cpp 
g++ main.o func.o -o main.out
```

Please help

Comment: Why func vs func1?

Comment: @UliSchlachter XD i misspelling when editing the question? i will edit it

Comment: Okay, so do you have the same typo in your program? If not, how are you invoking the compiler in the terminal?

Comment: How do the commands look like that you use in terminal?

Comment: @UliSchlachter I use g++ -c main.cpp

Comment: @UliSchlachter then g++ -c func.cpp g++ main.o func.o -o main.out

Comment: Works for me. What does `which g++` show?

Comment: what you have shown should work, which means you are not actually showing what you really did (probably)